# Create new List<T> out of 2 List<VM>

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I currently work on an ASP.NET MVC 4.5 application with EF 6. Currently I work on my linq query to store the data in the DB with Entity Framework.

My problem: in the query **SwotParts**, I need to create one `List<T>` which consists of two `List<VM>`. Thus merge two lists of same Type into a new one.

My query looks like this:

```
SWOT = vm.Swots.Select(x => new SWOT
{
    SwotForId = x.SwotForId,
    SwotParts = x.ExternalSwotParts.Select(y => new SwotPart
    {
        SwotTypeId = y.SwotTypeId,
        Label = y.Label
    },
    x.InternalSwotParts.Select(z => new SwotPart
    {
        SwotTypeId = z.SwotTypeId,
        Label = z.Label
    })).ToList()       
}).ToList()
```

Obviously this does not work, but I hope it shows the basic idea...

Here is my class **SWOT**:

```
public partial class SWOT
{
    public SWOT()
    {
        this.SwotPart = new HashSet<SwotPart>();
    }

    public int SwotId { get; set; }
    public SwotFor SwotForId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SwotPart> SwotPart { get; set; }
}
```

and the **SwotVm**

```
public class SwotVm
{
    // enum
    public SwotFor SwotForId { get; set; }
    public List<SwotPartVm> InternalSwotParts { get; set; }
    public List<SwotPartVm> ExternalSwotParts { get; set; }
}
```

and my class **SwotPart** :

```
public partial class SwotPart
{
    public byte SwotPartId { get; set; }
    public SwotType SwotTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Show the classes `SWOT` and `SwotPart`

Comment: How can you expect anyone to know what your talking about from that question?  What are you trying to do concat two lists into one and assign it to an object?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All you need is the `Concat()` method, which combines two sequences into one.

E.g:

```
SWOT = vm.Swots.Select(x => new SWOT
{
    SwotForId = x.SwotForId,
    SwotParts = x.ExternalSwotParts.Select(y => new SwotPart
    {
        SwotTypeId = y.SwotTypeId,
        Label = y.Label
    }).Concat(
    x.InternalSwotParts.Select(z => new SwotPart
    {
        SwotTypeId = z.SwotTypeId,
        Label = z.Label
    })).ToList()       
}).ToList()
```

Comment: Hi Brandon, Concat works as a charm, there is also Union, as far as I noticed. I basically used this query and added a null checker in a where clause: `.Where(q => q.Label != null)` thanks!

Comment: @TimHorton `Union` is similar to `Concat`, except that it removes duplicates.  Anyway, glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in method .ConvertAll() to help in this situation.

```
//merge the two existing lists
oldList1.AddRange(oldList2);

//make a new one converted into the new type
var newList = oldList1.ConvertAll(
    (originalElement) => new Blah(originalElement.Property)
);
```

Comment: How will convert all help in anyway here?

Comment: Because he needs to create "one List<T> which consists of two List<VM>." ConvertAll() lets him new up a "T" converting from "VM".

Comment: AddRange is a good one! will use ConvertAll next time ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SWOT = vm.Swots
    .Include(x => x.ExternalSwotParts)
    .Include(x => x.InternalSwotParts)
    .Where(...)
    .ToArray()
    .Select(x => new SWOT
{
    SwotForId = x.SwotForId,
    SwotParts = x.ExternalSwotParts.Select(y => new SwotPart
    {
        SwotTypeId = y.SwotTypeId,
        Label = y.Label
    }).ToList(),
    InternalSwotParts = x.InternalSwotParts.Select(z => new SwotPart
    {
        SwotTypeId = z.SwotTypeId,
        Label = z.Label
    }).ToList()
}).ToList()
```

First thing to notice, is you need to tell EF that you want to include the ExternalSwotParts and InternalSwotParts in your original query so that the inner select statements don't cause additional queries via EF lazy-loading.

Then, we call `ToArray` before the select, this causes EF to execute the SQL query immediately and load all of the Swots and SwotParts into memory. Then we can do any selects as normal inside as all of the data is now in memory.

Comment: @johnny5: I added it because i wanted to write some code that was actually valid C# - the posted code in the question is littered with mismatched brackets and parenthesis.

Comment: Yeah I know the question was unclear from the start he didn't post what was in the object he wanted to create, it seems like he wanted to merge those lists

Comment: thanks guys for your help, i really appreciate though!!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define your VM in your MVVM object.

```
public class CreateModelHouseViewModel
{
    public CreateModelHouseViewModel()
    {
    }
    public CreateHouseViewModel House { get; set; }
    public CreateAddressViewModel Billing { get; set; }    
}
```

// sample

```
var vm = new CreateModelHouseViewModel();

var pocoEntity = new PocoEfModel {propA=vm.House.propA};
```

// a list of entities

```
var pocoEntityList = new List<PocoEfModel>();
pocoEntityList.Add(New PocoEfModel {propA=vm.House.propA};
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is just wrong, it does not answer the op's question

Comment: But it was accepted as the answer, so it must have somehow answered the OP's question.  Though I don't see how.

Comment: I finally added a new property in my ViewModel, called SwotParts, in my Service class I merge InternalSwotParts and ExternalSwotParts into SwotParts, using AddRange. thanks!

Comment: @TimHorton All you needed to solve your problem was the Concat method though.  And this answer still has nothing to do with what you asked.  If none of the answers helped then don't accept any of them.  Accepting a non useful answer just makes this question confusing for future people with the same problem.

Comment: glad it worked out for you. repository pattern can be difficult to portray.